# Android - Drawable language

Tags: android, localization, drawable

I have 5 image buttons that I fit together in a main screen and everything looks great. But I try to add the images with other language so I create a folder named "drawable-pt" and put the images in Portuguese inside this folder ( with the same name in the images ). But when I load the application in a Portuguese phone the images are messed up, they are one above the other but with the portuguese language. If I change the language of the phone to English the main screen looks great, everything perfect.

Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0):

Are the images the same size in both folders?

Comment: Yes. I even try put the same images on both folders, and guess what ? When I load on portuguese language the images messed up.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue can be that one of your folders is drawable-hdpi and another drawable-pt. Rename it to drawable-pt-hdpi   or mdpi or whatever you use.